# status field with "given values" (list of valid values) in a class C# (.NET Core)

Tags: c#, validation, .net-core, parameters

I'm a C# beginner and looking for a simple option to store a status field in a class.

This field should only allow certain values like "open", "picked", "packaged", "shipped".

Later I'd like to filter a collection of orders according to this status field (by value).

```cs
namespace Prototype.Models
{
    public class Order
    {
        public string Id { get; }
        public string Status { get; }
        public int Priority { get; }
        
        public Order(string id, string status, int priority)
        {
            Id = id;
            Status = status;
            Priority = priority;
        }
    }
}
```

I read something about Ienumerable. But I'm not sure.

The type of the status field is not important as long as I can filter this.
A string would certainly be helpful. Something like an enum with statically specified values.

I also need a check when creating via constructor. Is there a way to try or throw an exception?

```cs
namespace Prototype
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var SampleOrder = new Order("id001", "picked", 123);
            
            Console.WriteLine(SampleOrder.Status);
        }
    }
}
```

It shouldn't be possible to instantiate an object that receives the status parameter "broken" via the constructor method.

Perhaps it can happen that the list of valid values for the status has to be expanded later. However, the list can be static.

It would also make sense if the status is readable (`public ... {get;}`). This return should be a "speaking" value, then.

Comment: Why not use an enum? This is exactly what they're for.

Comment: So typos are impossible, e.g. `"piked"`.

Comment: "Perhaps it can happen that the list of valid values for the status has to be expanded later. However, the list can be static." So what? Does it change or is it static?

Comment: @HimBromBeere: 
I add any missing status manually (in code), but this will occur very rarely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to define the enum, similar to a class, and then declare it as a class member, like so...

```
namespace Prototype.Models
{
    public enum OrderStatus
    {
        Open,
        Picked,
        Packaged,
        Shipped
    }

    public class Order
    {
        public string Id { get; }
        public OrderStatus Status { get; }
        public int Priority { get; }
    
        public Order(string id, OrderStatus status, int priority)
        {
            Id = id;
            Status = status;
            Priority = priority;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay. That seems comprehensible to me.
Sorry, but I never used enums in C# before.
So it's written like a class. Nice. I like that.
Thank you.